# ASP.NET: Server.MapPath returns the string NOT_A_VALID_FILESYSTEM_PATH

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET application, a method that is supposed to write a file to disk sometimes unexpectedly ends up writing the file with the filename `NOT_A_VALID_FILESYSTEM_PATH`.

The (simplified) code is:

```
private void WriteFile(string fileID)
{
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("/Data/" + fileID + ".xml");

    // (More code that writes data to that file...)
}
```

Why is Server.MapPath returning the string "NOT_A_VALID_FILESYSTEM_PATH"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) returns the string "NOT_A_VALID_FILESYSTEM_PATH" when both of the following are true:

1. The argument provided to Server.MapPath includes a character that can't appear in a valid filename, such as colon (":") or question mark ("?");
2. In the application's web.config file, the system.web / httpRuntime element includes the attribute [relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If the web.config doesn't have the `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"`, then the call to Server.MapPath will instead throw a System.NotSupportedException with the message "The given path's format is not supported."